# Changing default browser font-size affecting 3 divs floated inside a header div

Tags: css, browsers, fonts

Changing a web browsers default font size from 16px adversely affects the layout of the 3 divs that I have floated within my header div. Considering that the 3 header divs are fixed elements and not part of the site content or navigation as such, would it be better for me to fix the font size of the text in each div?

The affected site is [here](http://www.prosserandpikebuilders.co.uk/), if you change your browsers default font size to 15 or 17, for example, then you will notice that the positioning of the 3 divs becomes badly affected. I presume that this is due to me implementing the div floating incorrectly, the content div is configured the same as the header div but resizes elegantly if the font size is decreased or increased.

The other alternative would be for me to just implement an image rather than divs containing heading text but I would then lose the SEO benefits that the non-graphical text provides.

Many thanks in advance,
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, when dealing with text, especially within the main content area, I would suggest leaving the `font` fluid so that the user has as much control as needed in order to properly use the content.

However, in this circumstance, it is `header` text, which is already oversized and quite legible.

In this case, I would set a static `font-size` to maintain the design.

Comment: Thank you Jason, that confirms what I was thinking. Now I just need to get each browser to render the font size the same.

Answer (score 0):

The better option would be setting the static font size according to div.For different divs,we can use different font sizes and also we can use a default font size for the body maybe

```
font-size:12px
```